# How to select resolution as an input for a YouTube video using youtube_dl

Tags: python-3.x, youtube-dl

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
import youtube_dl

ydl_opts = {}
url = input("Enter your URL:")
with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(ydl_opts) as ydl:
    if
    ydl.download([url])
print("Downloaded!")
```

By default, it is downloading 360p videos. However, I want to download what is best resolution for that particular video. Could anyone help me? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Use the [format](https://github.com/ytdl-org/youtube-dl/issues/7937) option**

If you want the best video format use ***bestvideo***.

Example:

```
url = input("Enter your URL:")

ydl = youtube_dl.YoutubeDL({
    'outtmpl': '/tmp/testvideo.mp4',
    'format':' bestvideo+bestaudio'
})

ydl.download([url])
```

**Edit:** If you want to have the video and audio in 1 File, do:

```
'format':' bestvideo[ext=mp4]+bestaudio[ext=mp4]/mp4'
```

Instead of

```
'format':' bestvideo+bestaudio'
```

Comment: That was really good. Thank you for that. For someone who's gonna use the code, make sure to add a **,** after `'outtmpl': '/tmp/testvideo.mp4'`
It should look like this:
`'outtmpl': '/tmp/testvideo.mp4',
    'format':' bestvideo+bestaudio'`

Comment: I have just found that it is downloading the audio file and video file separately. How do I make this download a file that plays both audio and video at the same time?

Comment: I edited it so that you can merge both video and audio to 1 File

Comment: For people that have the same Question it would be easier if there was an accepted answer

Comment: Which video are you trying to download? Maybe there is no better quality available for the video.

Comment: I cannot reproduce the 360p downloading